# Android difficulty with menu popup

Tags: java, android, xml, jmenupopup

In Android, is it possible to design a menu popup as we would like too like give borders for the menu, change text colors ...?

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a question... but the answer is "yes, it's possible"

Comment: Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refered [Android Popup Menu](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)